Excel: plotting a number of cases with two dots each connected by a line
Objective: creating a visualisation of a number of cases, each consisting of two points (x|y), and illustrating the difference between these two using a line
Example: a table that records the dates and the prices at which a number of items were bought and sold
Consider the following data and the way they are visualised. We have five cases consisting of items that each were bought and sold at specific dates and specific prices.
The visualisation that I have in mind shows these five pairs of transactions with a "date" axis (x) and a "price" axis (y), and, most importantly, to illustrate the development of the prices, a line that, for each item, connects the "buy" and the "sell" dots.
90% of what I'm after is pretty straightforward:

Without much ado, I've managed to make Excel plot the "buys" (blue) and the "sells" (red). What's missing though is their connection. Here's a manual draft of what it should look like:

What are the necessary steps to achieve this? I suppose the problem in my current arrangement is that the main distinction is not between the five cases, but between the "buy" and the "sell" category (hence the misleading colours) -- but I'm clueless as to how to make the necessary change.


Choose the "Lines with Markers" option of the scatter chart.
You will need to pair up each data point as such:

Range for X Values is: =(Sheet1!$B$2,Sheet1!$D$2)
Range for Y Values is: =(Sheet1!$C$2,Sheet1!$E$2)
And so on.
Sample result:


That works perfectly! ...it just seems to require setting up each series (Item 1, Item 2...) manually. But pretty useful for smaller data sets, and a considerable step forward in my case.

A simpler option would be to reformat your data and again use the "Lines with Markers" option of the scatter chart.

Make sure to use the "Connect data points with line option


A bit hacky but it does the job.
Arrange your data in columns (buy date, sell date, #N/A, buy price, sell price, blank). You can do this manually, or using OFFSET formulae if you don't want to (or can't) change the original layout. The #N/A column is important.
Use the TOCOL function to flatten this into three columns. Cell Q2 is =TOCOL(OFFSET(G$2,0,0,COUNTA(G:G)-1,3)); cell R2 is =TOCOL(OFFSET(J$2,0,0,COUNTA(J:J)-1,3)); cell S2 is =TOCOL(OFFSET(M$2,0,0,COUNTA(M:M)-1,3)).
Draw a scatter plot. I've formatted the line with an arrow, and added data labels corresponding to the names in column S. You'll need columns N and O to be filled with empty strings (="") for the labels to look right. The #N/A values mean that the lines are broken between one sell and the next buy.
TOCOL is pretty new; you could achieve the same in older versions with some OFFSET formulae.

